# In Lightroom, how can I add a (visual) timestamp on photos based on the EXIF data?

Tags: lightroom, timelapse

When recording a long timelapse it would be nice to be able to show the current time in the corner of the final video. One easy solution to do this would be to use the EXIF data to add a timestamp to each photo.

Is it possible to do this within Lightroom or LR Timelapse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagemagik's mogrify tool is ideal for this. And with the LR adding "LR/Mogrify 2": https://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrmogrify2.php you can make it part of your export process in LR. I use it to stamp preview images with an image number so customers can identify which pictures they want.

The command you want to use is mogrify -annotate: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#annotate

The command line attributes for mogrify look daunting but their use forum are helpful and once you get it working you can just leave it :-). Here is an example form their users forum that is a good starting point for what you want: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20673#p82956

Note further in the post is discussion around running this on Windows - so depending on what platform you are it may or may not be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the free FastStone image viewer.

From an answer on https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-pictures/add-date-and-time-to-photo-image/49f5720b-0091-40c9-8698-44f36e96227c:

> FastStone Image Viewer
>   http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm
>
> I suggest that you create a new folder and add
>   copies of your photos for experimental purposes.
>   If you are unhappy with the result your originals
>   will be untouched.
>
> "Basic steps to add dates to image files
>   using Fast Stone Image Viewer"..
>   (FWIW...this is easier to do than it is to explain)
>
> (You'll have to experiment with position, font
>   size, color and the various Variables to achieve
>   the result you desire.)
>
> Tools / Open Batch Convert / Batch Convert tab...
>
> Check the box...Use advanced options...
>
> Advanced Options button / Text tab /
>   Check the box...Add Text...
>   (If the white field has any text in it...
>   clear it by selecting and press your Delete key...
>
> Open the drop window..."Insert a Variable"
>   choose...EXIF DateTime / Date and Time...OK...
>
> Browse to the files you wish to append...select
>   them and left click the Add button...
>
> Choose an Output Format...
>
> Choose an Output folder...
>
> Check the 'Rename' box...
>
> Click the Convert button...
>
> When the files are converted..click Done...
>
> Now browse to your save folder and see the result...